# Opcache equivalent function to apc store

Tags: php, apc, opcache

We need to upgrade the php version from 5.3 to 5.5 of one project that´s using APC. So, as I´ve seen in php 5.5 there is a new cache library to use instead of apc, opcache. I have read the docs and I have a few doubts.

Actually, in one specific part of the project we are using the apc `store` and `fetch` functions to store some data, but I haven´t seen any similar functions to do the same task with opcache. The question is simple, is it possible to do the same with opcache?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DarkBee does apcu works over opcache?

Comment: Yes, see link in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the `store` and `fetch` functions by installing `APCu`

`sudo apt-get install php5-apcu`

By installing `APCu` `extension_loaded('apc')` will return `true` as well
and you don't need to rename any of the old functions used.

I'm using this on a debian with PHP5.6 with OPCache enabled

[source](http://jessesnet.com/development-notes/2014/php-55-opcache-apcu/)

Comment: And, to use apc over opcache, the old apc extension doesn´t need to be installed, right?

Comment: Nope `apuc` replaces `apc`'s caching of user variables and `OPCache` is taking care of the `files`

Answer (score 1):

No you can not do it with OPCache. This module makes OPCode Caching only.